# Expected behavior with regular expressions with capturing-groups in pandas' `str.extract()`

Tags: python, regex, pandas, capturing-group

I'm trying to get a grasp on regular expressions and I came across with the one included inside the `str.extract` method:

```
movies['year']=movies['title'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*',expand=True)
```

It is supposed to detect and extract whichever is in parentheses. So, if given this string: `foobar (1995)` it should return `1995`. However, if I open a terminal and type the following

```
echo 'foobar (1995)` | grep '.*\((.*)\).*'
```

matches the whole string instead of only the content between parentheses. I assume the method is working with BRE flavor because of the parentheses scaping, and so is grep (default behavior). Also, [regex](https://www.regex101.com/) matches in blue the whole string and green the year (capturing group). Am I missing something here? The regex works perfectly inside python

Comment: grep by default returns the *lines* that match your pattern.

Comment: So, check out this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/can-grep-output-only-specified-groupings-that-match

Comment: Also, if you are on MacOsX, IIRC, `grep` has been stunted by removing the -P option.

Comment: I really keep forgetting that `grep` return the matching line

Comment: If my answer below answers your question please consider upvoting/accepting. Else, please drop a comment with details you still need clarifying.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the behavior of Pandas [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) is quite expected: it returns only the *capturing group* contents. The pattern used with `extract` requires at least 1 capturing group:

> `pat : string` 
>   *Regular expression pattern with capturing groups*

If you use a named capturing group, the new column will be named after the named group.

The `grep` command you provided can be reduced to

```
grep '\((.*)\)'
```

as `grep` is capable of matching a line *partially* (does not require a full line match) and works on a per line basis: once a match is found the whole line is returned. To override that behavior, you may use `-o` switch.

With `grep`, you cannot return the capturing group contents. This can be worked around with PCRE regexp powered with `-P` option, but it is not available on Mac, for example. `sed` or `awk` may help in those situations, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

`movies['year']= movies['title'].str.extract('.*\((\d{4})\).*',expand=False)`

- Set **expand= True** if you want it to return a DataFrame or when applying multiple capturing groups.
- A year is always composed of 4 digits. So the regex: **\((\d{4})\)** match any date between parentheses.